# manually entered path in autoload_namespace.php of vendor is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I put a path manually in the autoload_namespaces.php in the vendor directory of zf2 for custom library class file which is working in fine in windows local system but when I deployed this to linux server It stop working and giving the below error and please find the below code as I am using.

```
autoload_namespaces.php file
```

\vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
```

$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

```
return array(
'phpDocumentor' => array($vendorDir . '/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock/src'),
'ZendXml\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendxml/library'),
'Prophecy\\' => array($vendorDir . '/phpspec/prophecy/src'),
'Cron' => array($vendorDir . '/cron/cron/src'),
'' => array($vendorDir . '/bitweb/stdlib/src', $vendorDir . '/bitweb/stdlib/test', $vendorDir . '/bitweb/zf2-cron-module/src', $vendorDir . '/bitweb/zf2-cron-module/test'),
'Ikey' => array($vendorDir . '/'),
```

);

library class path path
\vendor\ikey\Mail\Mail.php

I am accessing in controller like
$ikey = new \Ikey\Mail\Mail();

error : \Ikey\Mail\Mail class not found

Note : Plese give me a solution why this is not working in linux server.

Answer (score 2):

The file you mentioned has this line in its header:

```
// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer
```

This means you are not supposed to edit it manually. What you should have been doing is editing the autoload section of your `composer.json` according to [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Something along the lines of:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Ikey\\": "Ikey/src/"}
    }
}
```